# Unable to Free a struct

Tags: c, struct, free

I was unable to free a struct. My understanding of 'free(void *)' is that after freeing the pointer, the variable & memory address can be reused. This is not the case below,

```
struct list {
  struct list_node * head;
  int size;
  };
typedef struct list list;

//create
list * create_list() {
    list * l = (list *) malloc(sizeof(list));
    l->head = NULL;
    l->size = 0;
    return l;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    list * l = create_list();
    free(l);
    list * l = create_list();

    return 0;
}
```

> main.c:25:12: error: redefinition of 'l'
>       list * l = create_list();
>              ^ main.c:23:12: note: previous definition is here
>       list * l = create_list();
>              ^ 1 error generated.

Comment: It has nothing do with `free` read error message properly.It says you are declaring `l` two times.

Comment: Deallocation of memory under a pointer will not undeclare a variable. You can only declare a variable in a scope once.

Comment: You define `l` for a second time in the same code block ...

Comment: After free l is still a pointer. But it points to an undefined memory section.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a variable twice in the same scope. That's why you get a redefinition error.

Your list pointer is a variable as well. You must not re-declare `l` in your main function.

Your compiler already knows that it's a `list *`, so you should remove the `list *` on line 19.

also i think you misunderstand what `free` does. it de allocates the memory that you allocated with `malloc` and thus makes the memory at the pointer's address unusable within your program. you must re use `malloc` (or you can directly use `realloc` without need to use `free` before).

Comment: `you can't declare a variable twice in the same function` If you could mention in the same scope instead of same function.